# Checking constraints at runtime

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a function that detects whether the type of an input satisfies a given constraint:

```
satisfies :: (c a => a -> b) -> a -> Maybe b

-- or the more general
claim :: (c => a) -> Maybe a
```

So the desired behaviour would be:

```
>>> :t satisfies @Show show
satisfies @Show show :: a -> Maybe String
>>> satisfies @Show show (0 :: Int)
Just "0"
>>> satisfies @Show show (id :: Int -> Int)
Nothing
```

The goal is to make it easy to define fully polymorphic functions that take
advantage of specializations when possible:

```
showAny :: a -> String
showAny (satisfies @Show show -> Just str) = str
showAny (satisfies @Typeable showType -> Just str) = "_ :: " ++ str
showAny _ = "_"
```

As the easiest thing I could try, my first attempt tried using `-fdefer-to-runtime`

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fdefer-type-errors -Wno-deferred-type-errors #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Claim where
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import System.IO.Error (catchIOError)

satisfies :: (c a => a -> b) -> a -> Maybe b
satisfies f a = unsafePerformIO $
  (return . Just $! f a) `catchIOError` \_ -> return Nothing
```

This failed because `-fdefer-type-errors` doesn't defer the checking to
runtime, or allow further checking to be done in the context which it is
actually used (as I had hoped), but instead at compile time replaces found
type errors with the equivalent of `error "MESSAGE"`.

Now I'm out of ideas. Is implementing `satisfies` even possible?

Comment: This could also horribly break parametricity. If something like this is ever available, it should require `Typeable a => ...` or some other mechanism to keep the type around at runtime (otherwise, after compilation they are normally erased.)

Comment: Good point. [parametricity](https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/05/parametricity/) for the lazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't dispatch on instance availability at runtime. Remember, a constraint is translated by the compiler into a *type class dictionary* - a record of functions that is passed around explicitly and accessed explicitly at runtime. The "fat arrow" `=>` is represented at runtime by a "thin arrow" `->`, so the elaborator needs to know at compile time which dictionary to pass around.

That is, the following crude example:

```
class Show a where
    show :: a -> String

instance Show String where
    show = id

showTwice :: Show a => a -> String
showTwice x = show x ++ show x

main = putStrLn $ showTwice "foo"
```

generates Core code which looks approximately like:

```
data Show_ a = Show_ { show :: a -> String }

showString_ :: Show_ String
showString_ = Show_ { show = id }

showTwice :: Show_ a -> a -> String
showTwice show_ x = show show_ x ++ show show_ x

main = putStrLn $ showTwice showString_ "foo"
```

When generating code for `main`, the compiler needs to know where to find `showString_`.

You can imagine a system wherein you can look up a type class dictionary at runtime with some sort of introspection mechanism, but this would produce weird behaviour from a language design perspective. The problem is orphan instances. If I write a function which attempts to look up a given instance in module `A`, and define such an instance in an unrelated module `B`, then the behaviour of that function when called from some client module `C` depends on whether `B` was imported by some other part of the program. Pretty strange!

---

A more usual way of doing "fully polymorphic functions that take advantage of specializations when possible" would be to put the function in question into a type class itself and give it a default implementation (perhaps with [a `default` signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures) if the default implementation depends on some superclass). Your `showAny` would then look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
import Data.Typeable

class ShowAny a where
    showAny :: a -> String
    default showAny :: Typeable a => a -> String
    showAny x = "_ :: " ++ show (typeOf x)
```

You'd need to implement `ShowAny` for all of the types with which you want to use `showAny`, but that's usually a single line of code,

```
instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => ShowAny (a -> b)
```

and you can specialise an implementation for a given type just by overriding `showAny`.

```
instance ShowAny String where
    showAny = id
```

You see this approach quite frequently in libraries which do generic programming. [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html), for example, can use `GHC.Generics` to serialise a given type to and from JSON (all you have to do is derive `Generic` and write two lines `instance ToJSON MyType; instance FromJSON MyType`), but you can also write your own instances of `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` if the generic code isn't fast enough or you need to customise the output.

Comment: Fully willing to grant the correctness of the first part of this answer and the difficulty of altering GHC to allow such behaviour.

I'm not terribly moved by the orphan instances argument, though. Orphan instances already have an associated warning and are (rightly) accused of weird effects. I don't see throwing one more on the pile as a reason to avoid implementing it.

I do appreciate the practical approach of the last section. It's a technique I've used before, and though I don't think it's as easy as using `satisfies` would be, the language is what it is.

Comment: With `data Proof c where QED :: c => Proof c`, `type Claim c a = Maybe (Proof (c a))` one could also write `showAny :: (Claim Show a, Claim Typeable a) -> a -> String`, so I suppose I was looking for similar sugar for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate workaround to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398811/9859) is to pass the dictionaries around manually.

That is, given:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Claim where

data Proof c where QED :: c => Proof c
type Claim c = Maybe (Proof c)
type c ? a = Maybe (Proof (c a))
```

One can write:

```
showAny :: (Show? a, Typeable? a) -> a -> String
showAny (Just QED, _) a = show a
showAny (_, Just QED) a = "_ :: " ++ showType a
showAny _ _ = "_"
```

Which works accepably well:

```
>>> showAny (Nothing, Just QED) (id :: Int -> Int)
"_ :: Int -> Int"
>>> showAny (Just QED, Just QED) (0 :: Int)
"0"
>>> showAny (Nothing, Nothing) undefined
"_"
```